# SQL Server : select the minimum value from table

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, select

I know it's simple question, but I still can't figure it out.

I want to find the date which is the closest date from now.

Here is my `product` table:

```
P_INDATE
----------    
2013-11-03  
2013-12-13 
2013-11-13
```

Basically, it should show `2013-12-13`.

I type this `SELECT Max( P_INDATE)   FROM product` and it work.

Then, I try to use  `MIN((GETDATE()- P_INDATE))` in the `where` condition, but I fail.

Comment: Do you need closest past date, or closest past or future date?

Answer (score 1):

Use `MAX` and `WHERE` clause along with function `GETDATE()`:

```
SELECT MAX(P_INDATE)
FROM product 
WHERE P_INDATE < GETDATE()
```

The above query gives you maximum date, which is less than current date, which you get using function `GETDATE()`

Comment: This work, but I just want to practice another way.. A way without `MAX(P_INDATE)`

Answer (score 1):

One way to go about this is to order the query by the difference between the stored date and the current date and take the first rows only. Using [`abs`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189800.aspx) will allow you to find the closest date regardless of whether its before or after the current date.

```
SELECT   TOP 1 p_indate
FROM     mytable
ORDER BY ABS(GETDATE() - p_indate) ASC
```

Comment: I have never consider this way, you have been a great help. Thanks,

Comment: getdate() - p_indate will return a datetime (if both are datetimes). ABS cannot handle the type datetime. Furthermore you can't subtract a date from a datetime(I am guessing p_indate has the type date)

Comment: yes, you are right, p_indate's type is datetime. So, how to order by `(GETDATE() - p_indate)`?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a column which stores data and you want to show only recent one every time,why cant you use

select max(date) from yourtable which will always give you recent date

Comment: I just want to try anther way. Practice more and more.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an index on the column, the most efficient method is probably a bit more complicated:

```
SELECT TOP 1 P_INDATE
FROM ((SELECT TOP 1 P_INDATE
       FROM product 
       WHERE P_INDATE < GETDATE()
       ORDER BY P_INDATE DESC
      ) UNION ALL
      (SELECT TOP 1 P_INDATE
       FROM product
       WHERE P.INDATE >= GETDATE()
       ORDER BY P.INDATE
      )
     )
ORDER BY ABS(DATEDIFF(second, P_INDATE, GETDATE()))
```

The subqueries will use the index to get (at most) one row earlier and later than the current date.  The outer `ORDER BY` then just needs to sort two rows.

Comment: It's complicated, I modify to this `SELECT TOP 1 P_INDATE
FROM PRODUCT
ORDER BY ABS(DATEDIFF(second, P_INDATE, GETDATE()))`  and it work.

Comment: @CodaChang . . . That works, but it requires sorting the entire table.  The purpose of this version is to maximize performance.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can try this:

```
SELECT TOP(1) P_INDATE
FROM [product table]
ORDER BY CASE 
            WHEN DATEDIFF(day,P_INDATE,GETDATE()) < 0 
            THEN DATEDIFF(day,GETDATE(),P_INDATE) 
            ELSE DATEDIFF(day,P_INDATE,GETDATE()) 
        END ASC
```

Comment: this work,too. Thanks. It's really a special solution.

Comment: By the way, hopefully it's the way your thought about it. It will give you the really closed date. Even if its after your provided date. Just as an example: If you give a date to it (not get_date()) which has a row 10 days in the past and 1 day in the future, it will return the date in the future. If you won't have this behavior, just remove the case and only use the code inside the `ELSE`.

Comment: By the way, please don't forget to mark any of the answers as your solution if another one comes across the same question again. It will be helpful and further improve stackoverflow. :-)